# Duda en haskell

Tags: haskell

```
data Persona = Persona String [String] Float String Bool deriving Show -- nombre intereses presupuesto lugar alergico
data Itinerario = Itinerario String [String] Float deriving Show -- lugar cualidades precio


presupuesto :: Persona -> Float
presupuesto (Persona _ _ devolver _ _) = devolver
intereses :: Persona -> [String]
intereses (Persona _ devolver _ _ _) = devolver

precio :: Itinerario -> Float
precio (Itinerario _ _ devolver) = devolver
cualidades :: Itinerario -> [String]
cualidades (Itinerario _ devolver _) = devolver

alcanzaPara :: Persona -> Itinerario -> Bool
alcanzaPara persona cosa = presupuesto persona > precio cosa

esApto :: Persona -> Itinerario -> Bool
esApto persona cosa = alcanzaPara persona cosa && opcion persona cosa

opcion :: Persona -> Itinerario -> Bool
opcion persona cosa
```

Mi problema es el siguiente, yo tengo que saber si una cosa es apto para una persona si esa cosa tiene cualidades que sean de interes para esa persona, por ejemplo, que vaya a un bar y la cualidad del bar es que tiene "noche de baile" y la persona justo tiene en su lista de intereses "noche de bailer".

Mi problema esta en que, cuando hago "esApto" debo ir a otra funcion llamada "opcion". Esto se debe a que la primer condicion es que debe alcanzar el presupuesto respecto al precio. La segunda condicion se divide en "x" condiciones. Depende si la actividad es ir a un restaurante, parque, de compras, etc...

Mi problema surge cuando tengo que preguntar, por ejemplo, el restaurante, el cual este posee cualidades como ["vegano", "puedeBailar", "aptoCeliacos"]
y mi persona digamos tiene los intereses ["vegano", "puedeBailar"]

Yo quiero preguntar en la funcion opcion si los intereses de esa persona concuerdan con las cualidades. O sea, si tanto "vegano" como "puedeBailar" se encuentran en la otra lista.
Como podria hacer esto?
Ya intente usar lambda, fold, etc... pero siempre me sale errores y ya me es muy molesto. Por ejempo:

```
opcion persona cosa = (e -> e `elem` cualidades(cosa) ) intereses(persona)

o si no

opcion :: Persona -> Itinerario -> Bool
opcion persona cosa
    | tipo == "Restaurante" = foldl (\e -> e `elem` cualidades(cosa)) False intereses(persona)
    
-- me da error en foldl y `elem`
```

Digamos algo asi, yo quiero que me devuelva "true" si cada elemento de la lista "intereses(persona)" estan dentro de la lista "cualidades(cosa)"

***Realmente esto se divide en mas opciones, o sea

opcion persona cosa
| Si es restaurante o bar ver si tiene tal cualidades
| Si es compras, ver si le alcanza la plata
| Si es parques, ver si es alergica

Aclaro esto por si surge esa duda mientras lee lo anterior y se tenga una mejor nocion del codigo

Comment: En resumen, quieres saber cómo comprobar que una lista está incluida en otra. Sin buscar en las funciones disponibles en `Data.List`, una forma rápida de saber su una lista `lst2` está incluida en `lst1`: `all (\`elem\` lst1) lst2`. Si lo prefieres como compresión de listas: `and [ elem x lst1 | x <- list2]`

Comment: Claro, pero eso es una lista dentro de otra lista. Lo que yo busco es tomar cada elemento de la primer lista y verificar si cada elemento de esta primera esta en la segunda lista. Ese es el problema, no encuentro forma de tomar cada elemento intente con: ```all(`elem` ((\e -> e)lista1)) lista2``` pero no funciona tampoco

Comment: Que cada elemento de la primera lista esté en la segunda es como se entiende que la primera lista esté contenida en la segunda. No entiendo bien la diferencia.

Comment: No, una cosa es comparar los elementos de una lista con los elementos de otra. Vos me estas hablando de listas dentro de otras listas [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]] por ejemplo. El programa no los toma por igual si yo intento ver si el elemento 1 de la lista [1,10,15] esta dentro de la lista [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]. En todo caso, deberia recorrer cada subelemento de cada lista dentro de la lista 2.

Comment: Al menos, si lo planteo como vos lo calcas, no me lo toma, me da errores porque nunca encuentra el elemento, ya que deberia entrar a cada sublista dentro de la lista2

Comment: Yo solo quiero que si tengo lista1 = [1,2,3] y si tengo lista2 = [4,5,1,2,3,7] me diga de alguna forma si al menos 1 de esos elementos [1,2,3] o todos ellos, se encuentran en lista 2

Comment: No, yo no estoy comparando listas con listas, sino los elementos de una lista con los elementos de otra, de que cada uno de los elementos de `[1,2,3]` están en la lista `[4,5,1,2,3,7]`: `all (\`elem\` [4,5,1,2,3,7]) [1,2,3]`

Comment: Listo, borre los msj anteriores porque era un poco en vano. Ya esta resuelto. Muchas gracias